# Twilio SMS api failed throw exception on XAMPP any port or IP to be oppened

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I integrate Twilio SMS API on PHP. And the code is working on GoDaddy hosting. But not working on local XAMPP. When I use open network it is working fine. But under company net work it is failing. Is there any port or IP to be opened on fire wall? Following is the code used.

```
require_once ("inc/Services/Twilio.php");
$strFromNumber = "+44xxxxxxxx";
$strToNumber = "+94xxxxxxxx";
$strMsg = "SMS test from twilio :".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$aryResponse = array();

$AccountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx15";
$AuthToken = "0bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb1";

$objConnection = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

try {

    $bSuccess = $objConnection->account->sms_messages->create($strFromNumber,$strToNumber,$strMsg);

} catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

$aryResponse["SentMsg"] = $strMsg;
$aryResponse["Success"] = true;

echo json_encode($aryResponse);
```

The error shown on local machine.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php:84 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio.php(112): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('post', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio.php(112): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->post('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array, 'From=%2B4474813...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\ListResource.php(89): Services_Twilio->createData('Accounts/AC6133...', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\CachingDataProxy.php(115): Services_Twilio_ListResource->createData('AC6133e1339b600...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\Resource.php(44): Services_Twilio_CachingDataProxy->createData('SMS/Messages', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\ListResource.php(59): Services_Twilio_Resource->createData('SMS/Messages', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\Rest\SmsMessages. in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\inc\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php on line 84
```

How to fix this issue on local windows based XAMPP? What is the port or IP need to be opened to allow this service over restricted net work?

Answer (score 1):

The isue is documented here:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/235279367-Twilio-PHP-helper-library-SSL-certificate-problem-on-Windows

There is an issue with the `php_curl` library on Windows. It doesn't use an up-to-date list of CA Root Certificates. You can get a `pem` file of the root certificates from the curl site.

To fix this issue please try the following:

1. Download the following pem file: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy this file to c:\cert\cacert.pem
3. Open php.ini file in your favorite editor ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) on where to find it)
4. If the following configuration string: `curl.cainfo` exists in your php.ini, please uncomment it by removing ";" and modify the path in order to point it to the cacert.pem file you downloaded, e.g:

   ```
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Module Settings ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

   curl.cainfo=c:\cert\cacert.pem
   ```
5. Please restart your Apache or IIS service to apply the change (very important!)

Please give that a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works on open network. But under my company net work it is not working. Do I have to open any IP or Port in firewall?

Comment: @sugunan your company may be using a proxy that decrypts the SSL traffic. You may need to contact them to get the CA Certificate they are using and add it to the `cacert.pem` file mentioned in the answer here (just copy/paste the contents to the end of the file). If they give you a binary file (e.g. der, p7b, or pfx), you can convert it to Standard PEM here: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html